# socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machi ne actively refused it

Tags: python, exception

I have a server-client application where server is online at a random time but client needs to send broadcast messages periodically in order to register to server when it's online. So i want my application to ignore the above error and keep on what it's doing till it gets a specific control trigger from the server.

Example code:

```
import socket,sys
cs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cs.connect((HOST, CPORT))
cs.send("REGS " + hostname)
cs.close()
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: So ignore it.  Catch the exception, whatever, it is completely unclear what kind of runtime environment you use.

Comment: import socket,sys

cs = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cs.connect((HOST, CPORT))
cs.send("REGS " + hostname)
cs.close()

there is no exception handling, when I run the app from console python app.py, application quits with the above error, i want it to keep sending.

Comment: Use proper tags for your question.  [python] tag added.

Answer (score 0):

Socket raises socket.error exception: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html

Now read up on how to use try-except for exception handling: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html